# How to Load balance on the basis of same content to the same backend server

Tags: load-balancing

I wanted to send all the requests for same content to the same backend server. How I can do this. Are there any open source versions like HaProxy which can do this.

For example. Client 1 has requested for Content A, and my load balancer directs that request to one of the backend server say X on round robin basis. Now if I receive a request from different client 2 for the same content A, this request should be directed to the same backend server X.
Are there any open source solution which can do this.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify you want destination affinity each node has same content and session state is not an issue?

Comment: yes you are right. I am not concerned much about each client session state. I am thinking on content based on the backend server. So if my load balancer knows content A is on server X, it should send any subsequent requests to the same X server. But this content is not pre configured. The load balancer will only come to know about the content if any previous request has been received for that content. Hope this is clear.